# Autosys Force-fun the Sub Boxes

Tags: autosys

My problem is simple,

I've 3 boxes.

```
-Restart Box (start_times:"23:30")
--Stop Box (start_times:"23:30")
   ---Stop This Job
   ---Stop That Job
--Start Box (start_times:"5:00")
   ---Start This Job
   ---Start That Job
```

Now my problem is the `force-run`. I want to be able to hit the `force-run` for Restart Box and have `Stop Box` and `Start Box` `RUNNING`.

However, as you can maybe imagine, instead it goes into `ACTIVATED` state, since it has `start_times` defined in it.

You may say that; don't define the `start_times` for the BOX, define them for the JOBS, but I have a lot of jobs under a box, so It's not very ideal to do that so.

PS: I don't have access to `sendevent`.

Any help & ideas are appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done with the same job as per my understanding. You can simply create another box job (adhoc) with no start times/schedule defined. It can be triggered once whenever you need it to run out of schedule and the stop box will run immediately after start box (stop box has a condition as success(start box)).